# React/CSS: Pushing the first element of ul to left and keeping the rest to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a nav bar with the logo to the left and the rest elements to the right. For some reason the `:first-child` keeps pushing all of the elements within ul to the left.

JS:

```
function Navigation() {
    return (

    <Navbar>
        <NavItem href="#" icon={<Logo />} />
        <NavItem href="#" icon={<About />} />
        <NavItem href="#" icon={<Idea />}>
            <DropdownMenu></DropdownMenu>
        </NavItem>
    </Navbar>
    );
}

function Navbar(props) {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">{props.children}</ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

function NavItem(props) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
    <li className="nav-item">
        <a href={props.href} className="icon-button" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        {props.icon}
        </a>
        {open && props.children}
    </li>
    );
}
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    height: var(--nav-size);
    background-color: var(--bg);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-bottom: var(--border);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -2px #252424;
}

/* <ul> */
.navbar-nav{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

.navbar-nav:first-child{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: If your navbar is a flexbox having flex direction row and you want to push some items to the right, the simplest thing to do is using margin:auto on the first item that you want to push right

Comment: two things 1. if you want to float first child it will be like .navbar-nav li:first-child{
    float:left;
}. 2. if you want to achieve want you want, it could be done by wrapping logo in one element and others in different then you can use justify property.

Comment: Take a look here https://codepen.io/EnricoMassone/pen/PoNqwxa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the logo from navbar list element? If yes, some flexbox config can align in the way you want.

```css
.navbar {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px -2px #252424;    
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: space-between;    
}

/* <ul> */
.navbar-nav{
    max-width: 100%;
    list-style:none;
    display: flex;
}

/*li*/

.nav-item{
  padding:12px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
 <div>Logo</div>
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item">
        Menu
    </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        Menu
    </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        Menu
    </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        Menu
    </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achive the effet that you want is pushing the flex item to the right by using margin left auto. Consider this markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My sample website</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-right"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the style.css file:

```
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.nav > .nav-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
```

All the trick is done by the nav-right class. By setting margin-left auto on a flex item the margin left will grow as much as possible, and the net result is pushing the flex item all the way to the right.

Here you can find the running example: https://codepen.io/EnricoMassone/pen/PoNqwxa